# File not showing last Character of string when written in file

Tags: c++, string, file-io, char

This snippet is part of a big program. The problem I am facing is that when I write a string to the file using "write" member function, it do not show last character of string:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    fstream file1("/users/xxxxxxx/desktop/file1.txt", ios::out);
    string data;
    cout << "Enter string: " << endl;
    getline(cin, data);
    file1.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&data), data.size());
    //file1 << data;
    file1.close();
    return 0;
}
```

For Example: If Input String: "Hello World".
On File it will show: "Hello Worl",
But it does work fine if I input string using "file1 << data". Please help me in this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why would you cast the address of a string into a char*? This isn't a meaningful conversion--you are casting a `std::basic_string<char>*` to `char*`. I suspect you want to treat string as char* since `write` accepts `const char*` as parameter. You can access the character sequence stored in your `data` by doing `data.c_str()`.

Answer (score 2):

`file1.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&data), data.size());`

Don't do this, you are writing the `string` object itself to the file. if you really want to use `write` you have to get a pointer to the first char that the string holds, like this:

`file1.write(data.data(), data.size());`

Just use the `<<` operator.

Comment: Thanks, but I also have a followup question: When to use **Write** and when to use **<<** operator to write in a file?

Comment: When you want to write unformatted binary data, you should use `ostream::write`. See http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/ for a more detailed explanation.